# How to hide contents of TEdit and copy to Clip board?

Tags: delphi

I am having one Delphi XE2 Project with 2 BitBtns and 2 TEdits. Both of the TEdits contain secret data, so I have hidden the contents. My requirement is copy the contents of TEdit1 to clipboard after BitBtn1 Click and similarly for TEdit2. Here is my sample code:
    unit Unit1;

```
interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons, Clipbrd;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Label5: TLabel;
    Label6: TLabel;
    Label7: TLabel;
    Label8: TLabel;
    Label9: TLabel;
    Label10: TLabel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Edit5: TEdit;
    BitBtn1: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn2: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn3: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn4: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn5: TBitBtn;
    procedure BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMainForm.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.PasswordChar := #0;
  Clipboard.Clear;
  Edit1.CopyToClipboard;
  Edit1.PasswordChar := '*';
end;

procedure TMainForm.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit2.PasswordChar := #0;
  Clipboard.Clear;
  Edit2.CopyToClipboard;
  Edit2.PasswordChar := '*';
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := 'User Name';
  Edit1.PasswordChar := '*';
  Edit2.Text := 'Password';
  Edit2.PasswordChar := '*';
end;

end.
```

But the problem is as follows:
1. If the `PasswordChar := '*';` is set, the contents can not be copied to clipboard.
2. If I compile my sample code, `TEdit1` Contents is copied to Clipboard after clicking `BitBtn1` but `TEdit2` Contents is not copied to Clipboard after clicking `BitBtn2`, though the first operation (`Clipboard.Clear;`) performs successfully.
3. If I double click on `TEdit2` then click on `BitBtn2` now `TEdit2` Contents is copied to Clipboard.
I don't know why it is happening so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no text is selected, CopyToClipboard does nothing.
Use this :

```
procedure TMainForm.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit2.SetFocus;
  Edit2.PasswordChar := #0;
  Clipboard.Clear;
  Edit2.CopyToClipboard;
  Edit2.PasswordChar := '*';
end;

procedure TMainForm.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.SetFocus;
  Edit1.PasswordChar := #0;
  Clipboard.Clear;
  Edit1.CopyToClipboard;
  Edit1.PasswordChar := '*';
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to place text in the clipboard, do so like this:

```
Clipboard.AsText := SecretEdit.Text;
```

or

```
Clipboard.AsText := SecretEdit.SelText;
```

The reason that the default behaviour of the control is to block copying to the clipboard is in case you walk away from your machine without realising that you left a password in plain text on your clipboard for a malicious attacker to steal. You should consider whether or not you want to take that risk with your application's users.